# Git-Svn dcommit causes branch splitting

Tags: svn, git, git-svn

I'm having a problem with git-svn dcommits making the git repository lose track of which commits are which.

I try to make sure that the master branch in git always follows trunk in the SVN repository. So whenever I'm working, I'm on a topic branch. Here's my scenario:

Working in a topic branch for a while

```
git checkout -b my-topic
git commit -m "blah blah blah"
```

Then I decide I'd like to merge my branch back in to master

```
git checkout master
git svn rebase #get any changes in svn
git rebase master my-topic
git merge my-topic --ff-only
```

Up until here, everything has gone well. I now have both master and my-topic up to speed and pointing at the same commit, and the entire history looks like this:

```
A -- B -- C - master + my-topic
```

However, when I do

```
git svn dcommit
```

I end up with a tree that looks like this (B and C are commits I originally made to the topic):

```
  -- B -- C - my-topic
 /
A -- B -- C - master + remotes/trunk
```

It seems like during the dcommit process, git pushes the commits up to SVN, then replays them back on top of master. The problem I think is that they get different committer information. I'm logging into svn with tortoise plink and an SSH key.

Commits in the git repository that have not been pushed to SVN have committer info as:

```
Collin Hockey <chockey@xyz.com>
```

Commits that have been pushed to the svn repository have this though:

```
chockey <chockey@6206317d-b652-48a9-a948-4036602fc523>
```

Is there any way I can keep these branches from splitting? I can sort of fix it by saying

```
git rebase master my-topic
```

again, but I feel like that should be unnecessary. The main problem with this is that once a branch's changes are pushed to SVN, git no longer thinks that branch has been merged anywhere. It makes it confusing to delete old branches you no longer need.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `git svn dcommit` command works as follows:

1. Find the last commit coming from SVN; let's call it `last-svn`
2. Send the commits in the range `last-svn..HEAD` to Subversion (discarding the e-mail by the way)
3. Reset the `HEAD` to `last-svn`
4. Update from SVN and create the corresponding commits

In other words, the commits you send to SVN are destroyed and recreated from the update from SVN. This must happen because the commits that come from SVN are different from the ones created with Git:

- Their description contains a reference to the SVN revision
- Their author e-mail is computed from the SVN username

That's why your branch `my-topic` diverges from `master`.

You can customize the way `git svn dcommit` computes the author e-mail from the SVN username with the `--authors-file` and `--authors-prog` options.

Comment: That seems to work a little better, but the commits are still different (They also have different times). Is there actually a way to prevent them from becoming new commits (or just update the commits on both branches automatically), or are these just the breaks of using the git-svn bridge?

Comment: @Collin This is the way git-svn works: SVN provides the commits, and Git faithfully reflects them. There is no way to change that behaviour (except by writing your own Git-SVN sync tool, of course).

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll just stick to rebasing my branch after dcommit-ing. The authors file stuff does make my history a lot prettier though :)

Answer (score 3):

you are right, that git replays the commits again from svn. branches in git are only pointers to commits (or there ids/hashes). the commits from svn will have different hashes, and only the currently checked out branch is updated by `git svn dcommit`, so your topic branch still points to the old commits