# Syncing existing git with existing SVN repository

Tags: svn, git, git-svn

Okay, I made a mess. I have a SVN repository with my code and I have a local git repository in which I usually work, branch, etc.. I used to commit things from time to time from git into SVN using git-svn. Now I got a new computer and cloned my git repository from one to the other. I tried to use git-svn afterwards, but due to a new version and me being not careful enough the configuration was somehow lost. So I used `git svn init` and `clone` to get back my history in SVN, but now the situation looks like this:

```
o--Z--o--....--X--o--o....--o  (master)
   |
   o--o--o--....--X (remotes/git-svn)
```

`X` is marking a state in which both repositories are in the same state (as master and git-svn where in sync on my old machine). Now, I'd like to commit everything from X to HEAD from `master` into my SVN repository, but when I use `git svn dcommit -n` it shows diffs way back to Z. How can I sync git-svn and git and svn again (so that I can use simply `dcommit` to commit stuff again)?

Is it possible to go back to `X` and use `git svn set-tree X` (because the current SVN holds exactly that version) and than go back to HEAD to do the `git svn dcommit`? I don't want to (blindly) try stuff on the SVN, as there is a lot of more stuff in it (by many other people) which I don't want to screw up.

Comment: git-svn creates a git repository that syncs to svn as if it were a remote. If you clone that git repository, you get a clone of the git repository, without any of the remotes, same as if you cloned a normal local git repo. If you want to retain the remote data, you could just copy the repository manually (which will keep the .git folder contents the same, retaining remotes). You can then add extra remotes from each copy of the git repository to the other, if you want that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git svn dcommit` looks back in the history of your branch until it finds a commit message that contains a `git-svn-id:` line, so it'll go back to `Z` in your case, as you observe.  I would try to rebase your `master` branch onto `remotes/git-svn`.  I haven't tested this, but the following would be what I would try:

```
 # Make sure that you're on master
 git checkout master

 # Create a new branch here to save the old branch
 git branch old-master

 # Rebase everything after the X on master up to the tip of master
 # onto remotes/git-svn
 git rebase --onto remotes/git-svn <commit-ID-of-X-in-master> master
```

After that, your history should look like:

```
o--Z--o--....--X--o--o....--o  (old-master)
   |
   o--o--o--....--X (remotes/git-svn) --o--o....-o (master)
```

... and `git svn dcommit` should work as expected - however, I'd try it with `--dry-run` first, just to be sure.

Comment: Thanks. That did what I asked for. Playing a little more with git-svn and git and svn I'm asking myself whether I'd be better off with another approach of keeping them in sync. As git-svn rebase does [strange things to the tree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595870/git-svn-dcommit-causes-branch-splitting) (which I think it hadn't done before), but this is another issue.